# “Show more” link in salary calculator should be “show less” when the list already expanded

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, mobile-web, salary-calculator

The “show more” link in salary calculator for mobile web should be titled “show less” when the list of items already expanded.

Initial state is correct:

> [image: correct]

Expanded state is incorrect because tapping on the link actually returns to the previous (collapsed state):

> [image: incorrect]

Comment: "Well, sometimes more is less" - [PHB](http://assets.amuniversal.com/41ce13706cc601301d50001dd8b71c47)